# Accessing current->mm from Kernel thread

Tags: process, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, scheduling, kernel

I have a requirement where I have a 'worker' kernel thread which wants to work on another process's 'mm' object. For some reason, I have to do it in kernel thread.

This 'mm' object is protected by 'mmu_lock'. Routines working on 'mm' uses 'current->mmu_lock', (which clearly means its not expected to be done from another context).

I understand kernel threads do not have a current pointer; and it simply uses 'current' pointer that was set for previous process. Thus, directly calling these routines from kernel thread is definitely wrong.

Given this is there any 'hack' to call these routines from kernel thread ? Like saving current pointer for required process and using that as 'current' pointer in kernel thread ? After a process is scheduled out(can it get swapped out?), is it safe to use its current pointer this way or simply cannot be done.

Comment: I won't answer your question, but I need to say: if you don't seem to be able to accomplish something using the actual kernel API, what you're trying to do is most probably wrong. Can you provide more details?

Comment: kernel threads do have a valid current pointer. You are confusing kernel thread with interrupt context where the current pointer is meaningless.